# How you tests application when test cases written by some other company

Tags: testing, automation, integration-testing

how you tests application when test cases written by some other company say some other testers from x company has written manual test cases and now my company A have been asked to understand and execute these test cases and show case the results to client.

What will be the ideal way?because i cant rewrite those cases

Comment: I've read this question like 5 times...the more i read it the more i get confused, i literally have no idea what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent of written test cases is to guide someone to execute the entire product for desired validations and also enabling them to explore further for edge/corner cases to find hidden issues, if any.

Hence my suggestion to you is:

01) Execute each test case step by step, it will help you know the product and validate it rightly. Also keep a status of each test case (probably important test step as well) result tracked to share later.

If result is passed, that's desired. If result is fail, that means either it is a bug there or some confusion in understanding/writing test case. So for other team Failed results are of more importance.

02) In case, if you have any issue with test case execution in understanding or doubt of it being wrong, share such test cases back with the other team to get clarity prior executing them.

And definitely you must not rewrite or edit any of the test case without approval from the other company. Good luck.